# My "Hello World" Angular JS is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm, hello.js

I have been following a tutorial to learn Angular js, and i am using Web Storm 9.0.1.

I have simply created a Html page and loaded the Angular.js file to the project. 
this is  my simple code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HelloWorldCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World ";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But all i get when i run the page is :`{{helloMessage}}` as a header 1 ! 
What should i do ? what i am missing here ?

Comment: should not you write `<html ng-app>` rather then `<html>` ?

Comment: the tutorial i was following missed to mention this point.

Answer (score 6):

You need:

```
<body ng-app>
```

This `ngApp` is needed to make understand AngularJS where it has to work

Here's your the working code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/lPOknrPD5dykwImL6Pb9?p=preview

Comment: For the future, there's no need to use Plnkr or JSFiddle anymore. StackOverflow has its own built in snippet execution. You just have to insert a code snippet in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just haven't initialized the Angular application. All you need to do is modify your `body` tag a bit. Notice the `ng-app` attribute in the body tag below:

```js
function HelloWorldCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

[check Angular hello word in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zEzhglYZJ16zBeoVuCdL?p=preview)

```
 <html ng-app="plunker">
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
       <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    </body>
  </html>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You always need to put the  directive first. You can also do it  in  or any other html tag. The ng-app directive tells the browser 'hey, this is an Angular app, let's see the script'. After the ng-app it will recognize all Angular directives.

It's also better practice to put the angular script loading at the bottom of the html, after the body. It's advised to load it last for performance and screen loading reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all, Yes indeed the problem was with the missing ng-app directive.
Note: the tutorial i was following missed this point!

A working Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>
</header>
<section>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function HelloWorldCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.helloMessage = "Hello World";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing the ng-app directive:

```
<body ng-app="">...</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code if you have not found any solution yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title> Hello World </title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div ng-app="HelloWorldApp">

        <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

    </div>

    <script>

        // INITIALIZE THE APP.
        var hello = angular.module('HelloWorldApp', []);

        // ADD THE CONTROLLER.
        hello.controller(
            'HelloWorldCtrl',
             ['$scope', function ($greet) {
                $greet.helloMessage = 'Hello World!';
             } ]
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have defined the "ng-app" directive inside the DIV element and later initialized it in the script. This way I can add multiple view and controller inside the DIV element.

For example. Add another DIV below the header tag.

```
  <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

  <div ng-controller="greet">
      <span> {{greetings}} </span>
  </div>
```

Later add this code inside the script tag.

```
    // ADD THE SECOND CONTROLLER.
    hello.controller(
        'greet',
        ['$scope', function ($greet1) {
            $greet1.greetings = 'Good Morning';
        } ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to define an AngularJS application on your page. The `ng-app` directive defines an AngularJS application. You can do it on your page like :

```
<html ng-app=""> or
```

`<body ng-app="">` or

`<div ng-app="">`

Make sure you do it before you start writing other angular JS code.

For more on the fundamentals of Angular JS  :

> http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp

Answer (score -1):

change you angular version to 1.2, I did it and it worked.
here it is:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js